# UNIT expected but PROGRAM found

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, pascal

```
program MouseInput;
Uses WinCrt,Mouse, sysutils,Graph;
Var
   GraphicsDriver, GraphicsMode,
   ErrCode : smallint;
   x, y: word;

Begin
x:=GetMouseX;
Y:=GetMouseY;

     Writeln('Initialising Graphics, please wait...');
     GraphicsDriver := Detect;
InitGraph(GraphicsDriver, GraphicsMode,'');
 x := GetmouseX();
 y := GetmouseY();
     OuttextXY(0,0,inttostr(x));
     readln();
end.
```

i have this code, but this syntax error occurs:
1 / 1 mouse.pas
 Fatal: Syntax error, UNIT expected but PROGRAM found
but this is a program not a unit ?

if i change Mouse to WinMouse it goes away, but throws out other errors saying identifier not found GETMOUSEX and GETMOUSEY

Comment: The compiler says you have a unit 'mouse.pas' that's starting with *program* but it should in fact start with *unit*. The code you posted is not what the compiler points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the folder units/rtl, you will find the unit files 'mouse.o' and 'mouse.ppu'. I think there is a conflict between the file names, because the compiler expects another unit file to update these. By changing the name of your file to 'mousetest.pas' the compiler did everything fine.

Comment: If he is using plain dos, there could be some SFN conflict too indeed.